Do we have the support in angular material for dynamically adding previous and next month dates in current month calendar?
For example if we check the calendar for June month we have may month dates and also july month dates as well. We are using angular material currently, but I dont these sort of examples there, can someone help us on this work item?

Since this "space" is used to show the month, it's impossible. anothers datepickers like in ng-bootstrap have this option, but not in material-angular.

No, this behavior is not supported in the current version of the API. There is an open issue in the material repository for this feature here, but it seems it didn't get much traction.
